# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, localhost

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource 
shows. It works fine in my local but not live server. On my Amazon Ec2
instance it shows this:

> Access to Font at 'sitelink/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3' from origin 'sitelink' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'sitelink' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> sitelink/:1 Access to Font at 'http://sitename/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3' from origin 'sitelink' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'sitelink' is therefore not allowed access.

My base URL in local is: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite';`

Comment: You can check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work for further information.

Comment: nope... that is helping me...